# What does 'go' mean in 'go show', 'go say', 'go want' etc and why no 'to' between?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does 'go' mean in 'go show', 'go say', 'go want', 'go do' etc and why no 'to' between?
What the difference between these pairs of words without 'to' and with 'to' as with the infinitive?

There are million examples in the internet:

> Several positive trends go to show this.  Let's go show them how it's
>   done. Go show them how great you are.

From old song:

> She go say anything man do himself fit do.  She go want take cigar
>   before anybody

Comment: I think the missing preposition is “and”  not “to”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these two examples of yours...

> Let's go show them how it's done.
>
> Go show them how great you are.

... both sound like colloquial speech where the preposition "and" has been dropped from the sentence. This seems to be common in American English, but not so common in British English.

> Let's go **and** show them how it's done.
>
> Go **and** show them how great you are.

As an aside, in *early modern English* it was common to prefix an order with "Go", although it would normally include a comma as in the biblical example "*Go, set a watchman*". Interestingly when this quotation was used as the title of an American novel by Harper Lee the comma was not included.

Your other example is different though:

> Several positive trends go to show this.

There doesn't appear to be anything missing from this sentence, although it may be idiomatic. The sentence is saying that data "goes towards", or "contributes to" showing something. It is a less dogmatic way of saying that some data absolutely proves something to be true - it just goes towards proving it.

Answer (score 0):

This use of "go" immediately followed by a verb is colloquial American English (it is hardly used in British English). It has been around for a long time, as is shown by the words of the old spiritual "Go tell it on the mountain".

A fuller form is either "go to" or "go and" - the latter also seen as colloquial.

The song you quote is a bit different - it is in a dialect which some regard as a separate language: [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAVE).